# Setting threshold in Sohn & al. (1999) Voice Activity Detection Algorithm

Tags: likelihood, signal-processing

In [1] an algorithm based on statistical modeling of the frequency bins of a signal in order to determine if it contains speech or not. There is two hypothesis H0 (speech absent) and H1 (speech present) under which the probability density function (pdf) is calculated for each frequency bin.

The Likelihood Ratios of these pdf's are then computed and the geometric mean is compared to a certain threshold $\eta$.

I wanted to know how to set the threshold $\eta$ to decide whether or not rejecting the null hypothesis. I looked into type I error but I am not sure if it is the right direction.

Reference:

[1] Sohn, Jongseo, Nam Soo Kim, and Wonyong Sung. ["A statistical model-based voice activity detection."](http://sipl.technion.ac.il/new/Teaching/Projects/Winter2011-12/1999%20-%20A%20Statistical%20Model-Based%20Voice%20Activity%20Detection.pdf) IEEE signal processing letters 6.1 (1999): 1-3.

Comment: Do you want me to migrate this question to Cross Validated?

Comment: @PeterK. Yes please.